# How to generate link map file for Clang on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, clang

I know for armcc(armlink), I can use -L--map flag to generate a map file. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474c/BABDJCAA.html

But for clang compiler and linker, I tried all these flags, but none of them can generate link map file:

flag1: xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7s -Wl,-dead_strip **-Wl,--map** -o exe objtest.o libtest.a

flag2: xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7s -Wl,-dead_strip **-Wl,-M** -o exe objtest.o libtest.a

flag3: xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7s -Wl,-dead_strip **-Wl,-m** -o exe objtest.o libtest.a

What's wrong with my flag? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Try `-Wl,-map,output.map`, that should do it.

Comment: Accept this as answer then? :-)